# java add text inside circle image

Tags: java, awt

I have that image:

[image]

And I need to add text to image, so I want to write method that recieved 2 strings and add them to image, for example:

```
addText(String str, String str2){...};
```

first string always be 3 chars lenth
second string can be from 1 to 20 chars length

addText("str", "secondstr");

And as result I want to recieve base64 png image string looking like that:

[image]

The main problem is how to write text in a 'circle format'? I need to change Y coordinate of each char what I write?

**UPDATE1:**
Explored link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm, but text always draws from left side, how I can move them to center of my circle?

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm

Answer (score 1):

The important part is this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      Point2D p = gv.getGlyphPosition(i);
      double theta = (double) i / (double) (length - 1) * Math.PI / 4;
      AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(p.getX(),
          p.getY());
      at.rotate(theta);
```

here it defines an angle theta and makes it loop from 0 to length/length*Math.PI/4, so it's a rotation from 0° to 45°. What you need to do is to play with the value theta (using also negative numbers) to make it start and finish where you want.

From the image you posted, it seems that the first string has to go from -20° to 20° (or from 340° to 20°), and the second from 225° to 135°. Note that these degrees have to be transformed in radians to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please find example how to write text along some curve here:
[draw text along curve](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The following sample program will print the string in a circular way. The `degIncrement` variable is the distance between characters in degrees.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RoundTextSample extends JFrame{
    public RoundTextSample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-400)/2, (screenSize.height-300)/2, 400, 300);

        add(new SamplePanel());
    }

    class SamplePanel extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            addText(g2, "str", "secondstr");
        }
    }

    public void addText(Graphics2D g2, String string1, String string2) {
        int radius = 40;
        Point center = new Point(120, 120);

        double startDegAngle = 0, offsetAngle;
        double degIncrement = 15, strImageWidth, charWidth;
        boolean isInverted;

        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();

        charWidth = font.createGlyphVector(frc, "A").getGlyphOutline(0).getBounds2D().getWidth();

        // compute start deg for string1
        offsetAngle =  ((string1.length() * degIncrement) - (degIncrement)) / 2.0;
        startDegAngle = 0 - offsetAngle;

        isInverted = false; // for top text
        addText(g2, string1, font, radius, center, isInverted, startDegAngle, degIncrement);


        // compute start deg for string2
        offsetAngle =  ((string2.length() * degIncrement) - degIncrement) / 2.0;
        startDegAngle = 180 + offsetAngle;
        isInverted = true; // for bottom text
        addText(g2, string2, font, radius, center, isInverted, startDegAngle, degIncrement);

    }

    public void addText(Graphics2D g2, String text, Font font, int radius, Point center, boolean isInverted, double startDeg, double degIncrement) {
        AffineTransform at;
        double deg;

        deg = startDeg;

        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        if (!isInverted) {
            radius -= font.createGlyphVector(frc, "A").getGlyphOutline(0).getBounds2D().getHeight();
        } else {
            degIncrement = 0 - degIncrement;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            String s = ""+text.charAt(i);
            GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, s);
            Shape glyph = gv.getGlyphOutline(0);
            double charImageCenterX = glyph.getBounds2D().getCenterX();

            double theta = Math.toRadians(deg);

            int xp = (int)Math.round(Math.sin(theta) * radius);
            int yp = (int)Math.round(Math.cos(theta) * radius);
            yp = 0 - yp;

            if (isInverted)
                at = new AffineTransform( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, center.x + xp, center.y + yp );
            else
                at = new AffineTransform( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, center.x + xp, center.x + yp );

            at.rotate(theta);
            at.translate(0-charImageCenterX, 0);

            Shape transformedGlyph = at.createTransformedShape(glyph);
            g2.fill(transformedGlyph);

            deg += degIncrement;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RoundTextSample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Output Notes:

[image]